# More than 2 columns in a CONCAT function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation

In SQL Server 2012 I want to `concat` 5 columns into 1 but in the query it works but when I put in in a view it gives me an error like

> Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   The CONCAT function requires 2 argument(s).

What's the problem so I can fix it because `concat` is a good function for `concatenate` more than 1 column because if its null they make it empty..

CODE:

```
SELECT        
   'Aan ' + A.Name AS 'Naam', 
   { fn CONCAT('T.a.v. ', C.Salutation + ' ', C.FirstName + ' ', C.MiddleName + ' ', C.LastName) } AS 'T.a.v.',   
   ISNULL(ISNULL(A.Address1_Line2, A.Address1_Line1), 
   C.Address1_Line2) AS 'Adres', 
   ISNULL(A.Address1_PostalCode + ' ' + A.Address1_City, A.Address2_PostalCode + ' ' + A.Address2_City) AS 'Woonplaats',
   'heer' + ' ' + ISNULL(C.MiddleName + ' ', N'') + ISNULL(C.LastName, N'') AS 'Aanhef'  
FROM            
    dbo.Account AS A 
FULL OUTER JOIN  
    dbo.Contact AS C ON A.Name = C.AccountIdName  
WHERE 
    (C.Salutation = 'Dhr.') AND (A.Name IS NOT NULL) AND (A.StatusCode = 1) 
    AND (ISNULL(C.StatusCode, 1) = 1) OR (C.Salutation = 'dhr.') AND (A.Name IS NOT NULL) AND (A.StatusCode = 1) AND (ISNULL(C.StatusCode, 1) = 1)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: You can try to `IsNull(columnName1, '') + IsNull(columnName2, '')...` if there is no other solution.

Comment: that is what i've tried before but you have to look here http://raresql.com/tag/concat-function/ this is faster

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/4805

Comment: For anyone reading this `{fn CONCAT(...)}` is an ODBC scalar function, not the T-SQL built-in function `CONCAT(...)` available from SQL Server 2012 onwards.  The github link above mentions that the view designer does not recognize the built-in function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There must be an error somewhere else in your view!!

Ok, then what I did with your code was to change this line

```
{ fn CONCAT('T.a.v. ', C.Salutation + ' ', C.FirstName + ' ', C.MiddleName + ' ', C.LastName) } AS 'T.a.v.'
```

to this

```
CONCAT('T.a.v. ', C.Salutation + ' ', C.FirstName + ' ', C.MiddleName + ' ', C.LastName) AS 'T.a.v.'
```

Edit:

Just to explain the difference in code, is that the one with { fn ....} is a Canonical function and microsoft promise that it will work on all ODBC connections.

From MSDN:

Canonical functions are functions that are supported by all data providers, and can be used by all querying technologies. Canonical functions cannot be extended by a provider.

Comment: no there isnt because ive used the same query but then with INSNULL(expresion1,'') ect and that was working..

Comment: In other words {fn CONCAT(...)} is 'ODBC' function that accepts only 2 arguments, while plain CONCAT(...) is SQL Server 2012 function that accepts many arguments.

Comment: do you realy now my problem ??
the problem is when i put the correct code into a view the view change the code from CONCAT to {fn CONCAT(

Comment: Ok, that was not easy to know from the description. Are you writing your view in SSMS or using some kind of tool because, this is not happening for me when i write my views!

Comment: @Jeroen the view is only doing that because you are using the horribly crappy and buggy view designer. If you edit the code of your view in a normal query window, this won't happen. So instead of right-click > modify/design, choose right-click > script as alter to > new query window.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand, thx for clearing that up for me, as I have never used that view designer, as i find it utterly useless ;o)

Answer (score 18):

Hy. If you want to use CONCAT as a canonical function {fn CONCAT(...)} into view designer, there is a work-around solution in order to concatenate more than two columns/chars.

You can use CONCAT inside CONCAT like this:

Let's suppose you want to concatenate two codes into a single one with a "-" between

column1 = 123456

column2 = 0001

```
{fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT(column1, '-')}, column2)}
```

As a result you will have: 123456-0001

Comment: The solution of @kenneth-m-nielsen worked for me until I had to use CAST(x) for some of the columns. in that cast, this was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and all the other answers did not work for me and i did not want to use the one from Andrei.

I managed to create the view using a create view statement.

```
CREATE VIEW ViewName AS
SELECT        
   'Aan ' + A.Name AS 'Naam', 
   { fn CONCAT('T.a.v. ', C.Salutation + ' ', C.FirstName + ' ', C.MiddleName + ' ', C.LastName) } AS 'T.a.v.',   
   ISNULL(ISNULL(A.Address1_Line2, A.Address1_Line1), 
   C.Address1_Line2) AS 'Adres', 
   ISNULL(A.Address1_PostalCode + ' ' + A.Address1_City,     A.Address2_PostalCode + ' ' + A.Address2_City) AS 'Woonplaats',
   'heer' + ' ' + ISNULL(C.MiddleName + ' ', N'') + ISNULL(C.LastName, N'') AS 'Aanhef'  
FROM dbo.Account AS A 
FULL OUTER JOIN  
    dbo.Contact AS C ON A.Name = C.AccountIdName  
WHERE 
    (C.Salutation = 'Dhr.') AND (A.Name IS NOT NULL) AND (A.StatusCode = 1) 
    AND (ISNULL(C.StatusCode, 1) = 1) OR (C.Salutation = 'dhr.') AND (A.Name IS NOT NULL) AND (A.StatusCode = 1) AND (ISNULL(C.StatusCode, 1) = 1)
```

Comment: That last one helped me out, thanks.  SQL kept changing my nested CONCAT in the designer of a new View to the {fn CONCAT ....}.  I just used my working SQL code before the designer changed it.  THANKS!!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. Here is how it happened. I used the query/view builder in SQL Server (2014) Management Studio. I typed the function "CONCAT (...", yet it transformed it to "{fn CONCAT(...)}". Then I got the error despite having more than one item.

I got rid of the "{fn ... }" and it worked fine.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONCAT_WS` instead of `CONCAT`.
It will be kept untouched in a view even if you use it in design mode in SSMS, and with it you can specify a string separator that will not be appended at the end of the string.

Example:

```
select CONCAT_WS('; ',NULL,'Frank',NULL,'Mary')
```

The result will be `Frank; Mary`

Answer (score 1):

create CONCAT FUNCTION in view SQL Server **must requires 2 arguments**. So you can try this :

```
SELECT
concat(
    concat('T.a.v. ', C.Salutation + ' '), 
    concat(C.FirstName + ' ', concat(C.MiddleName + ' ', C.LastName)) 
)  AS 'T.a.v.'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me that's worked so fine !
**select  (column1 + column2 + column3) as myconcat from myview**
instead {fn CONCAT({fn CONCAT(column1, '-')}, column2)}

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when I wanted to create view using designer and the ssms designer automatically added fn{ exp ….} but I instead used script,
Cerate View ViewName
my concat script

this worked with no issue