# SQL Server: Best way to concatenate multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to concatenate multiple columns in a query in SQL Server 11.00.3393.

I tried the new function `CONCAT()` but it's not working when I use more than two columns.

So I wonder if that's the best way to solve the problem:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(COLUMN1,COLUMN2),COLUMN3),COLUMN4) FROM myTable
```

I can't use `COLUMN1 + COLUMN2` because of `NULL` values.

**EDIT**

If I try `SELECT CONCAT('1','2','3') AS RESULT` I get an error

> The CONCAT function requires 2 argument(s)

Comment: The CONCAT function is [not limited to two arguments](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87f62/3) so this is not likely to be your problem. You could always use `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` to avoid the problems with `NULL`

Comment: I'm guessing you have a syntax error somewhere. Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: @JChao I'm simply trying SELECT CONCAT('1','2','3') AS RESULT

Comment: Are you using the native concat function, or the [canonical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738534%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) one (`SELECT { fn CONCAT('A', 'B', 'C') };` or `SELECT CONCAT('A', 'B', 'C')`, the former only allows two arguments, the latter accepts a variable number.

Comment: @GarethD I'm writing it in VisualStudio and everytime I write SELECT CONCAT('A', 'B', 'C') it overwrites  (SELECT { fn CONCAT('A', 'B', 'C') };

Comment: Don't use the canonical `CONCAT()` function:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567121/more-than-2-columns-in-a-concat-function

Comment: @Goat CO I am not using canonical CONCAT(). Maybe it's a configuration in VisualStudio2010?

Comment: Thats why I still use SSMS and avoid writing queries in Visual Studio :)

Comment: You stated above that you are... `(SELECT { fn CONCAT('A', 'B', 'C') };`

Comment: You have a visualStudio2010 going against a 2012 SQL Server DB?

Comment: `CONCAT()` was introduced in SQL 2012, so it makes sense that VS 2010 is converting it to what it knows.

Comment: @GoatCO should I answer the question with this information?

Comment: So either install Visual Studio 2012/SQL Server 2012 SSMS to use CONCAT or use the +COALESE(Column,'') way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Through discourse it's clear that the problem lies in using VS2010 to write the query, as it uses the canonical `CONCAT()` function which is limited to 2 parameters.  There's probably a way to change that, but I'm not aware of it.

An alternative:

```
SELECT '1'+'2'+'3'
```

This approach requires non-string values to be cast/converted to strings, as well as `NULL` handling via `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(50)),'')
      + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),Col2),'')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT(LOWER(LAST_NAME), UPPER(LAST_NAME)
       INITCAP(LAST_NAME), HIRE DATE AS ‘up_low_init_hdate’)
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIRE DATE = 1995
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below:

```
SELECT 
    (RTRIM(LTRIM(col_1))) + (RTRIM(LTRIM(col_2))) AS Col_newname,
    col_1,
    col_2 
FROM 
    s_cols 
WHERE
    col_any_condition = ''
;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

Using concatenation in **Oracle SQL** is very easy and interesting. But don't know much about MS-SQL.

> Blockquote

Here we go for Oracle : 
Syntax: 
`SQL> select  First_name||Last_Name as Employee
        from employees;`

### Result: EMPLOYEE

EllenAbel
SundarAnde
MozheAtkinson

Here AS: keyword used as alias.
We can concatenate with **NULL** values.
e.g. : columnm1||Null

Suppose any of your columns contains a **NULL** value then the result will show only the value of that column which has value.

You can also use **literal character string** in concatenation.

e.g. 
`select column1||' is a '||column2
from tableName;`
Result: column1 is a column2.
in between literal should be encolsed in single quotation. you cna exclude numbers.

**NOTE**: This is only for oracle server//SQL.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone dealing with [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com)

Try using [CONCAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html) with multiple columns like so:

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT(col1, col2, col3) AS all_string_columns_together
    , CONCAT(CAST(col4 AS VARCHAR(50), col1) AS string_and_int_column
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can pass multiple arguments to the CONCAT function in sql server not limited to 2.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
Also the + does not do an implicit conversion if one of the columns is numeric while concat does that.

Answer (score -3):

If the fields are nullable, then you'll have to handle those nulls. Remember that null is contagious, and `concat('foo', null)` simply results in `NULL` as well:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL(column1, ''),ISNULL(column2,'')) etc...
```

Basically test each field for nullness, and replace with an empty string if so.

Comment: In the [CONCAT Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh231515.aspx) Null values are implicitly converted to an empty string, this isn't necessary.